# Running .net core without SDK but with runtime

Tags: linux, .net-core

I have two .net core applications running on Linux.

One of them is happy with .net core runtime while another one is demanding .net core SDK.

I can build both applications using dotnet publish with the following parameters:

```
dotnet publish Web/Web.csproj -o publish -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained false
```

Both projects target 3.1 (checked .csproj):

```
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

I am deploying them to the same VM server which has .net 3.1 runtime installed:

```
 .NET Core SDKs installed:
    No SDKs were found.
 .NET Core runtimes installed:
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.10 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.10 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

However, on start of one of those projects as systemctl service I am getting an error:

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
       https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

While I can successfully start the application manually using `dotnet Web.dll`

1. Does my build artifact requires SDK?
2. Any ideas how can I troubleshoot this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

1- No, it shouln't require SDK

2-  Hard to help you with the incomplete question

- Have you tried to run the service with SDK installed? To check if that is the actual problem or just a misleading error.
- Are you using Systemd integration package by Microsoft?

  ```
  dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd
  ```

Comment: >Are you using Systemd integration package by Microsoft?
No, but I just noticed that other app is using developer error page.